# PHP basic login system login borken

Tags: php, html, web

hello i have made a basic php login system(not using PDO) as i have not gotten to grips with basic php.

the problem i am having is that when i try to login to the system it just redirects me to a php page and does nothing.

please be gentle :S

here is my code.

```
   <?php
if($logged_in == 1)  
  {
  die('You are already logged in, '.$_SESSION['name'].'.');
  }
//----------------------------------------------------------------
//Escape any Dangerous SQL Characters in the text
//----------------------------------------------------------------
function QuoteSmart($value, $handle)
  {
  if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
    $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
  if (!is_numeric($value))
    {
    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle) . "'";
    }
    return $value;
  }
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) //if the form has been submitted
  {   // check they filled in what they were supposed to and authenticate */
  if(!$_POST['txt_email'] | !$_POST['txt_password']) 
    {
    die('You did not fill in a required field.');
    }
  // authenticate the username and passsword.
  $email = $_POST['txt_email'];
  $password = $_POST['txt_password'];

  //------------------------------
  //Connect to the database
  //-----------------------------
  $server = "zzz";
$schema = "Marwick";
$uid = "xxx";
$pwd = "yyy";

  $password =$_POST["txt_password"];
  $email =$_POST["txt_email"];



$db_connect = mysql_connect($server , $UserID , $PassWord);
$db_select = mysql_select_db($schema, $db_connect);


  if ($db_select)
    {
    $email = QuoteSmart($email, $db_connect);
    $password = QuoteSmart($password, $db_connect);
    $SQL =   "SELECT * FROM account WHERE email = $email AND password = $passwordword";
    $Result = mysql_query($SQL);
    $NumberRows = mysql_num_rows($Result);
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Check to see if the value of the $result variable is true
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    if ($Result)
      {
      if ($NumberRows == 1)
        {
        $ErrorMessage = "Logged On";
         header("Location: home.html");  //The page to go to
    }
      else
        {
    $ErrorMessage = "Not logged on";
        header("Location: login.html");  //Try to login again
    }
      }
      mysql_close($db_connect);
        }
  else
    {
    $ErrorMessage = "Error with the Form!";
    }
  }
?>


  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
  <input name="btn_login" type="submit" class="btn_ragister" value="Submit"; onclick="" />
</form>
form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="">

  <input name="btn_register" type="button" class="btn_ragister" value="Register" 
    onclick= "window.location ='../Pages/register.html' "/>
</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$SQL =   "SELECT * FROM account WHERE email = $email AND password = $passwordword";`  looks like a typo ... did you really mean `$passwordword` ?

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. You're not checking that your query succeeded - try a call to `mysql_error()` to see if there's anything in there. Also, your DB password (and I hope those aren't live credentials) is in `$pwd`, but you're connecting using `$PassWord`.

Comment: Dont for the love of cats, store plain-text passwords in database!!!

Comment: Thanks for posting your MySQL host + username + password.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is FULL of syntax errors:

```
if(!$_POST['txt_email'] | !$_POST['txt_password']) 
                        ^---not a valid operator
```

and

```
$SQL =   "SELECT * [..snip..] AND password = $passwordword";
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^-undefined variable
```

In short, you need to learn basic debugging techniques.

As well, the mysql_*() functions are deprecated and obsolete. Do **NOT** learn how to use them, since you're just starting out in PHP. Learn mysqli (note the **i**) or PDO instead.